# SSRS DateDiff having errors due to syntax

Tags: reporting-services

I tried a few ways of doing this but keeps erroring out. Have to convert a Crystal report to SSRS. Suggestions?

Crystal

```
DateDiff ("d",{CRSS_INSP_DET.NEXT_INSP_DTE},CurrentDate())
```

SSRS - both of these do not run

```
DateDiff("day", Fields!INSP_DTE.Value), Today())
DateDiff("day", Fields!INSP_DTE.Value), Now())
```

It says this

> The Value expression for the textrun
> 'WRK_AAR7.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30516]
> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DateDiff' accepts
> this number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `)` in your expression.

```
DateDiff("day", Fields!INSP_DTE.Value, Today())
DateDiff("day", Fields!INSP_DTE.Value, Now())
```